# How make data bind with angularJS using img element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to put a default image into img element.

If I get an error loading the image or the image is null/undefined I´d like to put a default image

I have the next markup:

//controller

```
$scope.img_default="//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png"
```

//markup

```
<img  onerror="this.src='+{{img_default}}+'"
                    class="drop-box-filled-totem img-responsive"  
                    style="width:100%; height: 100%; max-height: 350px;"
                    ng-src="{{mobileCart||img_default}}"/>
```

But it doesn´t work.

If  I use the image url right into html, it works as below.

Is there a way to make it work using data bind by controller?

```
<img  onerror="this.src='//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png'"
                    class="drop-box-filled-totem img-responsive"  
                    style="width:100%; height: 100%; max-height: 350px;"
                    ng-src="{{mobileCart||'//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png'}}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code works fine for me

```
<img  class="drop-box-filled-totem img-responsive"  
      style="width:100%; height: 100%; max-height: 350px;"
      ng-src="{{mobileCart||img_default}}"/>
```

[Here is the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/22fyF95Md49jXJxi2nHS?p=preview), I think adding `onerror` attr is not what you should do because it is not informed about the angularjs `$digest` cycle.

From my understanding, on `onerror` you add some event [which is triggered](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp). you can achieve the same check in the controller itself. Just take into account that angularjs has its own digest cycle which should be taken care of.

Comment: OK, My problem is really in "onerror". I managed to do it with a function